# Find $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{\sin\left(x+2y\right)}{x+y}$

Tags: limits

Find the limit: $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \dfrac{\sin\left(x+2y\right)}{x+y}$$

where $x>0, \space y>0, \space y < x^2$

I guess it is $1$ and missing one side from using Squeeze theorem.
$\dfrac{\sin\left(x+2y\right)}{x+y} \geq  \dfrac{\sin\left(x+y\right)}{x+y}$

Comment: Consider (x,0)->(0,0) and (0,y)->(0,0) .

Comment: Oops I'm sorry I ignored the inequality part. I guess we can't set x and y to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1.*** Let $x,y$ be small positive such that $y<x^2$. Then
$$
\left|\frac{\sin y}{x+y}\right|\leq\left|\frac{\sin y}{x}\right|\leq\left|\frac{y}{x}\right|<\left|\frac{x^2}{x}\right|=x.
$$
It follows that
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{\sin y}{x+y}=0,
$$
where $x,y>0$ and $y<x^2$. Therefore
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{\sin (x+2y)}{x+y}&=&\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{\sin (x+y)\cos y+\cos(x+y)\sin y}{x+y}\\
&=&\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{\sin (x+y)}{x+y}\cos y+\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{\sin y}{x+y}\cos(x+y)\\
&=&1+0\\
&=&1.
\end{eqnarray*}

**Solution 2.** Let $x,y$ be small positive such that $y<x^2$. We have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\sin (x+y)}{x+y}&\leq&\frac{\sin (x+2y)}{x+y}\\
&\leq&\frac{\sin (x+2y)}{x}\\
&\leq&\frac{x+2y}{x}\\
&<&\frac{x+2x^2}{x}\\
&=&1+2x.
\end{eqnarray*}
Since
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{\sin (x+y)}{x+y}=1,
$$
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}(1+2x)=1,
$$
we have
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{\sin(x+2y)}{x+y}=1.
$$

Answer (score 6):

Let $x$ and $y$ be small positive, with $y\lt x^2$.  Then
$$\frac{\sin x}{x+x^2}\lt \frac{\sin(x+2y)}{x+y}\lt \frac{\sin(x+2x^2)}{x}.$$
It is not hard to show that
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\sin x}{x+x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\sin(x+2x^2)}{x}=1.$$
(For the second limit, multiply top and bottom by $1+2x$.) Now squeezing does it.

Comment: thanks. but I do not see the first line so trivial. you are doing opposite operation one make it larger, other make it smaller.

Comment: I had a "typo" in the first inequality. For the first inequality, we have $\sin x\lt \sin(x+2y)$ and $x+x^2\gt x+y$,  It follows that $\frac{\sin x}{x+x^2}\lt \frac{\sin(x+2y)}{x+y}$. A similar idea shows the second inequality (this time we increase the numerator and decrease the denominator).

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}\sin(x + 2y) &= \sin x\cos2y + \cos x \sin 2y \\&=\left(x -\frac 1 6x^3 +\cdots\right)(1 + \cdots) + \left(1 - \frac 12 x^2 + \cdots\right)(2y+\cdots)\\ &= x + 2y+\cdots\\
&= x+\cdots \text{ for }y < x^2.\\
x+ y &=x + \cdots \text{ for }y < x^2.
\end{align}$$

therefore $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \dfrac{\sin\left(x+2y\right)}{x+y} = 1. $$

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the easier limit of (x+2y)/(x+y) multiplying by (x+2y)/(x+2y).